# Outlook 2010 Macro throws VBA error 'For loop not initialized'

Tags: vba, outlook, runtime-error

I got this bit of code from someone's blog years ago.  It basically iterates through all the Outlook mail rules, and executes them (handy to organize your inbox!).  I've recently upgrade to Outlook 2010 from 2007.  Now I get a very strange error stating

```
Run-time error '92':
For loop not initialized
```

However, while debugging this, it will always run through 8 times (out of 20-25), then it throw this error.

Here is the offending code:

```
Sub RunAllInboxRules()

    Dim st As Outlook.Store
    Dim myRules As Outlook.Rules
    Dim rl As Outlook.Rule
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim ruleList As String

    'get default store (where rules live) & get rules
    Set st = Application.Session.DefaultStore
    Set myRules = st.GetRules

    'iterate all the rules
    For Each rl In myRules
        If rl.RuleType = olRuleReceive Then         'determine if it’s an Inbox rule, if so, run it
            rl.Execute ShowProgress:=True
            count = count + 1
            ruleList = ruleList & vbCrLf & rl.Name
        End If
    Next

    'tell the user what you did
    ruleList = "These rules were executed against the Inbox: " & vbCrLf & ruleList
    MsgBox ruleList, vbInformation, "Macro: RunAllInboxRules"

    Set rl = Nothing
    Set st = Nothing
    Set myRules = Nothing

End Sub
```

***Edit:***

Per Jay Riggs's comment, clearing the entire for block still results in the error.

Comment: Since it always runs only 8 times, is there anything special about the 9th rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue ended up being that some of the rules referred to a PST file I missed on moving to my new machine.  Thanks to Justin for forcing me to take a deeper look at the rules!

+1 to the obscure error message for this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd replace this loop with something like:

```
Dim k as Long
For k = 1 To myRules.Count ' might be 0-based, didnt check
    set rl = myRules(k)
    If rl.RuleType = olRuleReceive Then         'determine if it’s an Inbox rule, if so, run it
        rl.Execute ShowProgress:=True
        count = count + 1
        ruleList = ruleList & vbCrLf & rl.Name
    End If
Next
```

I bet there is some rule at position 8 or 9 that doesn't fit into the `myRules` collection and that throws the error. You can also check the `myRules` collection at the offending point. Maybe Office 2007 was more forgiving and skipped that entry.